# How can I reduce coupling in my Event Bus implementation

Tags: c++, events, decoupling

In my application, I have several modules that don't fit an 'is-a' or 'has-a' relationship, but still need to communicate and pass data to each other. To try and loosely couple these modules, I've implemented an Event Bus class that handles message passing from 'event posters' to 'event listeners'.

Classes can implement `IEventListener` if they wish to register to receive certain events. Likewise, classes can call `EventBus::postEvent()` if they need to push an event out to the bus. When `EventBus::update()` is called EventBus processes the queue of scheduled messages and routes them to registered listeners.

**EventBus.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <memory>


class IEvent
{
public:
    static enum EventType
    {
        EV_ENEMY_DIED,
        EV_ENEMY_SPAWNED,
        EV_GAME_OVER
    };

    virtual ~IEvent() {};
    virtual EventType getType() const = 0;
};


class IEventListener
{
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(IEvent * const e) = 0;
};


class EventBus
{
public:
    EventBus() {};
    ~EventBus() {};

    void update();
    void postEvent(std::unique_ptr<IEvent> &e);
    void registerListener(IEvent::EventType t, IEventListener *l);
    void removeListener(IEvent::EventType t, IEventListener *l);

private:
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<IEvent>> m_eventBus;
    std::map<IEvent::EventType, std::set<IEventListener *>> m_routingTable;
};
```

**EventBus.cpp**

```
#include "EventBus.h"


using namespace std;


/**
 * Gives the EventBus a chance to dispatch and route events
 * Listener callbacks will be called from here
 */
void EventBus::update()
{
    while (!m_eventBus.empty())
    {
        // Get the next event (e_local now owns the on-heap event object)
        unique_ptr<IEvent> e_local(move(m_eventBus.front()));
        m_eventBus.pop();

        IEvent::EventType t = e_local->getType();
        auto it = m_routingTable.find(t);
        if (it != m_routingTable.end())
        {
            for (auto l : ((*it).second))
            {
                l->handleEvent(e_local.get());
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Posts an event to the bus, for processing and dispatch later on
 * NB: The event bus will takes ownership of the on-heap event here
 */
void EventBus::postEvent(unique_ptr<IEvent> &e)
{
    // The EventBus now owns the object pointed to by e
    m_eventBus.push(unique_ptr<IEvent>(move(e)));
}

/**
 * Registers a listener against an event type
 */
void EventBus::registerListener(IEvent::EventType t, IEventListener *l)
{
    // Add this listener entry
    // If the routing table doesn't have an entry for t, std::map.operator[] will add one
    // If the listener is alredy registered std::set.insert() won't do anything
    m_routingTable[t].insert(l);
}

/**
 * Removes a listener from the event routing table
 */
void EventBus::removeListener(IEvent::EventType t, IEventListener *l)
{
    // Check if an entry for event t exists
    auto keyIterator = m_routingTable.find(t);
    if (keyIterator != m_routingTable.end())
    {
        // Remove the given listener if it exists in the set
        m_routingTable[t].erase(l);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in my current implementation, I create concrete IEvent implementations for every type of event I want to pass around. I did this so that each event can have custom data attached to it (a requirement for my situation). Unfortunately, this means my EventBus system has to know about all the users of the system, increasing the coupling between my EventBus class and the users of the class. Additionally, the IEvent interface needs to hold a list of all event types as an enum, which has the same problem (increased coupling).

1. Is there a way to modify this implementation so that EventBus can be totally generic (doesn't need to know about the users of the EventBus), and yet still allow me to pass custom data with each event? I looked into C++11 variadic template functions but couldn't figure out how to use them in this case.
2. As a side-question, am I using `std::unique_ptr` correctly here?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1** *"Is there a way to modify this implementation so that EventBus can be totally generic"*:

Short answer, yes.

Longer answer: There are many ways of accomplishing this. One is described here:

Both the producer and the consumer of the event needs to agree on the type/data but the `EventBus` itself does not need to know. One way of accomplishing this could be to use `boost::signals2::signal<T>` as the event type. This will give you a proven, flexible and type safe signal/slot implementation. What it will not provide, however, is the possibility to queue up slot callbacks and process them from the `EventBus::update()`-function.

But, that can also be remedied. By making the event type `EventBus::postEvent()` takes as a parameter be `std::function<void()>` and calling `postEvent()` like this:

```
boost::signals2::signal<int> signal;
...
eventbus.postEvent(boost::bind(signal, 42));
// note: we need to use boost::bind (not std::bind) for boost::signals to be happy
```

The `EventBus` will see a `std::function<void()>` and dispatch to the slot. The data (42 in this example) will be kept by the result of `boost::bind` and be used as the parameter when the slot is called.

**Question 2** *"Am I using `std::unique_ptr` correctly":*

Almost. I would drop the reference of `EventBus::postEvent` making it:

```
void EventBus::postEvent(std::unique_ptr<IEvent> e);
```

By doing this, you force the caller to actively move the `std::unique_ptr<IEvent>` into the `EventBus`. This will make the user aware the `EventBus` takes ownership and also making it obvious to people reading the code what the intent is and how ownership is transferred.

> [CppCoreGuidelines R.32](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-uniqueptrparam):
>
> *"Take a unique_ptr parameter to express that a function assumes ownership of a widget"*